# how to convert 2d array to 2d object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

So I'm trying to pass some JSON objects from NODE to client side JavaScript though EJS templates. The issue I'm facing is that i cannot create a 2D object from my 2D array. The code below is used in NODE to pass the object into the EJS template:

```js
let json_jobs = {};
let singleJSON = {};
let array_jobs = [
  ["aaaa", "title_1", "fulltime", "location1"],
  ["bbbb", "title_2", "parttime", "location2"],
  ["cccc", "title_3", "fulltime", "location3"],
  ["dddd", "title_4", "flex", "location4"]
];

for (let i = 0; i < array_jobs.length; i++) {
  singleJSON = {
    index: i,
    id: array_jobs[i][0],
    title: array_jobs[i][1],
    contract_type: array_jobs[i][2],
    location: array_jobs[i][3]
  }
  console.log(typeof(singleJSON ));
  console.log(singleJSON );
  
  json_jobs += {
    job: singleJSON[i]
  }
}
console.log(typeof(json_jobs));
console.log(json_jobs);

//return res.render('pages/searchJobs', {job_data: array_jobs});
```

The issue is that i cannot add push object using the `+=` operator and there is no function `push()` to use for javascript objects? Any ideas how to solve this?

This is what i want my final object to be:

```
    let json_jobs= {
      {
          job: {
              index: 0,
              id: "aaaa",
              title: "title1",
              contract_type: "fulltime",
              location: "location1"
          },
          job: {
              index: 1,
              id: "bbbb",
              title: "title2",
              contract_type: "parttime",
              location: "location2"
          },
          ....
      }
```

Comment: please add the raw data, you have and the wanted result as well.

Comment: Why don't you use an array as the value?

Comment: Question is updated

Comment: You would need to use an array, you cannot have duplicate keys in a JS object, like you show (`job:`)

Comment: And as you notice `job:` is redundant. Use an array instead. Also, why twice the `{{` that's an invalid Object without property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could destructure the row and return an object with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
let array_jobs = [ ["aaaa", "title_1", "fulltime", "location1"], ["bbbb", "title_2", "parttime", "location2"], ["cccc", "title_3", "fulltime", "location3"], ["dddd", "title_4", "flex", "location4"]],
    result = array_jobs.map(([id, country, contract_type, location], index) =>
        ({ index, id, country, contract_type, location }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: legend, nice and easy. Thanks a lot

Comment: i will mark this as an answer once a get the needed reputation

Comment: @user14054150 you already have the necessary reputation to mark the Answer as correct. The checkmark should not be hard spot. Just wait the grace-time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The `job` property must be an array to store multiple objects.

```js
let json_jobs = {jobs: []};
let singleJSON = {};
let array_jobs = [
  ["aaaa", "title_1", "fulltime", "location1"],
  ["bbbb", "title_2", "parttime", "location2"],
  ["cccc", "title_3", "fulltime", "location3"],
  ["dddd", "title_4", "flex", "location4"]
];

for (let i = 0; i < array_jobs.length; i++) {
  singleJSON = {
    index: i,
    id: array_jobs[i][0],
    title: array_jobs[i][1],
    contract_type: array_jobs[i][2],
    location: array_jobs[i][3]
  }
  json_jobs.jobs.push(singleJSON);
}
console.log(json_jobs);
```

Comment: if it's an array a plural would be best. Anyways - Anyways, I find `"jobs":` to be a redundancy as well. One could simply `const jobs = [...]` and job done.